# Не получается выпустить обновление для игры в гугл плей

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сегодня хотел обновить приложение сделанное на юнити, но консоль выводит такую ошибку, что делать?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подписать приложение в момент сборки тем ключом, которым подписывался самый первый бандл.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, помогли)